# How to reset RDBMS value when browser crashes

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex

This is my first post on these forums, however I've been using them for years in looking for solutions to my coding challenges...thank you for all for sharing your knowledge.

Ok, to the point...I need a nudge in the right direction for a theory of a solution to the below problem.

**Desired Result:**

Current existing structure: FLEX RIA that communicates with MySQl DB via PHP.

We basically, have a RIA that is part of a software solution we provide to our customers, we want to restrict login sessions to one/username, which we did successfully by setting a value in our MySQL DB...the point of this was to restrict the use of username(s) to one application access point and create the ability for us to charge for additional usernames, if so desired by our customer.

**Problem:**

Although, we successfully restricted user logins to one session, we ran into a problem when the RIA connection with the DB was inadequately terminated (eg., browser crash, OS crash, flash player error, etc). When these crashes happenned the value that was set in the DB for the user, showing them logged in, would persist and thusly lock them out of our software application. We would have to go into the database and manually reset their logged in status.

**What I am looking for:**

I need some suggestions or some areas to look into/research for a solution to this problem

Any help you might provide is greatly appreciated,
Thank You

Dignified Dude

Answer (score 0):

When the Flex app pings your server for the first time; create a server side session.  When that session expires, flip the value of the database automatically, regardless of whether or not the user has logged out.  You may also want to add some form of timer to the UI to automatically log the user out.

I assume there is some way to run code in PHP when the server side session expires.  Here are some approaches that came up in a Google Search:

[Run query after session expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334727/run-query-after-session-expire)

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1320013

[PHP session timeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287064/php-session-timeout-callback)

http://www.google.com/search?q=Run+code+when+PHP+session+expires&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=run+code+on+PHP+session+expire&pbx=1&oq=run+code+on+PHP+session+expire&aq=f&aqi=q-w1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=9504l13039l1l13162l32l12l0l0l0l0l1160l5043l2-4.2.1.3.0.1l11l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=9fb4160009134867&biw=1200&bih=786

Comment: Great suggestions, I'll check them out and come back if I have any further questions related.  Thank You